# how to use Hornetq with struts2 under glassfi

Tags: java, struts2, glassfish, hornetq

How can i use Hornetq in struts2 to increase the performance of my web application which should retrive 1400 records from database

Comment: HornetQ is for sending messages, not storing things. You probably want to look into a caching solution.

Comment: 1400 records isn't that many--it's more likely the issue is with how you marshall them from the DB into objects, the query itself, etc. In any case, as others have mentioned, the question doesn't make much sense.

Answer (score 0):

Hornetq provides high efficiency messaging between distributed systems: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_oriented_middleware

It has little to no impact on how fast it will take to retrieve any number of records from a database.  This is more of a factor of the db api used (JDBC vs JPA), the method of caching, the implementation of the database and hardware/network concerns when accessing it.  If you needed the highest possible speed in sending and receiving many messages between two servers, this is what Hornetq is built for but if it is to retrieve and send many records at once then there will probably be negligible difference.

Integration... I would not think there would be any integration of struts2 and Hornetq.  You can use spring to instantiate the service and spring services would be used by both Hornetq and struts2 but neither would have any awareness of each other. This is hinted at here: https://community.jboss.org/wiki/HornetQGeneralFAQs (But you need to read between the lines from the answers "Is HornetQ tightly coupled to JBoss Application server?" and down)